# Flutter app crashes on iOS more frequently after XCode/Flutter upgrade

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, crash

I am not sure if it's because of the XCode or Flutter upgrade, but the app crash rate went from ~ 0.5% to ~5-8%. Talking about real devices, app downloaded from App Store.

Any help is very welcome. Logs are below. I had to reduce the text size, so removed binary images and Threads 13-29. Will try to add them as a comment below.

```
Incident Identifier: 1B55BCEB-E43F-44B7-9E9A-1D0FDA358716
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,8
Process:             Runner [790]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/56173D3D/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.rangar.rangarr
Version:             30 (1.4.11)
AppStoreTools:       14E221
AppVariant:          1:iPhone12,8:13
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.rangar.rangarr [403]


Date/Time:           2023-05-09 19:37:36.9022 -0400
Launch Time:         2023-05-09 19:30:14.2538 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.7.1 (18G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.05.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  3

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   grpcpp                          0x00000001045f4f7c std::__1::shared_ptr<grpc::Server::GlobalCallbacks>::~shared_ptr[abi:v15006]() + 0 (shared_ptr.h:700)
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001af039270 __cxa_finalize_ranges + 408 (atexit.c:284)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001af0395c4 exit + 28 (exit.c:81)
3   flutter_exit_app                0x000000010326c9f4 SwiftFlutterExitAppPlugin.quit(killIosProcess:) + 8 (SwiftFlutterExitAppPlugin.swift:32)
4   flutter_exit_app                0x000000010326c9f4 specialized SwiftFlutterExitAppPlugin.handle(_:result:) + 856 (SwiftFlutterExitAppPlugin.swift:17)
5   flutter_exit_app                0x000000010326c1d8 specialized SwiftFlutterExitAppPlugin.handle(_:result:) + 12 (<compiler-generated>:0)
6   flutter_exit_app                0x000000010326c1d8 @objc SwiftFlutterExitAppPlugin.handle(_:result:) + 76
7   Flutter                         0x00000001050f62c4 __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 112 (FlutterChannels.mm:291)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104bab820 invocation function for block in flutter::PlatformMessageHandlerIos::HandlePlatformMessage(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformMessage, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delet... + 116 (platform_message_handler_ios.mm:75)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a587ca84 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1466)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a587e81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a588cc70 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 884 (inline_internal.h:2557)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c0b340 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c05218 __CFRunLoopRun + 2524 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
15  GraphicsServices                0x00000001bd287734 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a868275c -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3269)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a8687fcc UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4740)
18  Runner                          0x0000000102d58328 main + 64 (AppDelegate.swift:6)
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a58c0cf8 start + 4 (:-1)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ed14fc mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ed0884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c0ae58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a6ef3d8c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:377)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a6ef3c58 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:424)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a8737304 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 516 (UIEventFetcher.m:929)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a706530c __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef89bc poll + 8 (:-1)
1   grpc                            0x0000000103e5e240 pollset_work(grpc_pollset*, grpc_pollset_worker**, long long) + 1260 (ev_poll_posix.cc:1026)
2   grpc                            0x0000000103e600a8 pollset_work(grpc_pollset*, grpc_pollset_worker**, long long) + 72 (ev_posix.cc:323)
3   grpc                            0x0000000103e43cec cq_next(grpc_completion_queue*, gpr_timespec, void*) + 320 (completion_queue.cc:1047)
4   grpcpp                          0x00000001045deb80 grpc::CompletionQueue::AsyncNextInternal(void**, bool*, gpr_timespec) + 60 (completion_queue_cc.cc:146)
5   FirebaseFirestore               0x00000001033ab844 grpc::CompletionQueue::Next(void**, bool*) + 52 (completion_queue.h:185)
6   FirebaseFirestore               0x00000001033ab844 firebase::firestore::remote::Datastore::PollGrpcQueue() + 104 (datastore.cc:145)
7   FirebaseFirestore               0x00000001034be980 std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()[abi:v15006]() const + 20 (function.h:512)
8   FirebaseFirestore               0x00000001034be980 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const + 20 (function.h:1197)
9   FirebaseFirestore               0x00000001034be980 firebase::firestore::util::Task::ExecuteAndRelease() + 184 (task.cc:102)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a587e81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a5886004 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 620 (inline_internal.h:2557)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a5886c00 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 404 (queue.c:3862)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a58914bc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764 (queue.c:6589)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197e7a4 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2436)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f198574c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef6334 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197da9c pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1582)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001af058b84 abort + 124 (abort.c:118)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3da7c fml::KillProcess() + 12 (logging.cc:144)
4   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3dbe8 fml::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 4 (logging.cc:131)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3dbe8 fml::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 364 (logging.cc:75)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41d78 fml::internal::ThreadLocalPointer::swap(void*) + 184 (thread_local.cc:32)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3f120 fml::ThreadLocalUniquePtr<fml::(anonymous namespace)::TaskSourceGradeHolder>::reset(fml::(anonymous namespace)::TaskSourceGradeHolder*) + 12 (thread_local.h:50)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3f120 fml::MessageLoopTaskQueues::GetNextTaskToRun(fml::TaskQueueId, fml::TimePoint) + 440 (message_loop_task_queues.cc:140)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3f120 fml::MessageLoopImpl::FlushTasks(fml::FlushType) + 1716 (message_loop_impl.cc:122)
10  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41e48 fml::MessageLoopImpl::RunExpiredTasksNow() + 8 (message_loop_impl.cc:139)
11  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41e48 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::OnTimerFire(__CFRunLoopTimer*, fml::MessageLoopDarwin*) + 32 (message_loop_darwin.mm:85)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c0c1d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1807)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c0bdd0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1076 (CFRunLoop.c:2415)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c0b220 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 328 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04fd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1944 (CFRunLoop.c:3090)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
17  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41f34 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 88 (message_loop_darwin.mm:51)
18  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 28 (message_loop_impl.cc:94)
19  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::MessageLoop::Run() + 32 (message_loop.cc:49)
20  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::Thread::Thread(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0::operator()() const + 160 (thread.cc:85)
21  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 decltype(std::declval<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPA... + 160 (invoke.h:403)
22  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 160 (thread:284)
23  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 208 (thread:295)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ed14fc mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ed0884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c0ae58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41f34 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 88 (message_loop_darwin.mm:51)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 28 (message_loop_impl.cc:94)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::MessageLoop::Run() + 32 (message_loop.cc:49)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::Thread::Thread(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0::operator()() const + 160 (thread.cc:85)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 decltype(std::declval<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPA... + 160 (invoke.h:403)
10  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 160 (thread:284)
11  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 208 (thread:295)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ed14fc mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ed0884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c0ae58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41f34 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 88 (message_loop_darwin.mm:51)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 28 (message_loop_impl.cc:94)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::MessageLoop::Run() + 32 (message_loop.cc:49)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 fml::Thread::Thread(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0::operator()() const + 160 (thread.cc:85)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 decltype(std::declval<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPA... + 160 (invoke.h:403)
10  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 160 (thread:284)
11  Flutter                         0x0000000104e41a24 void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 208 (thread:295)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__libcpp_condvar_wait[abi:v15000](_opaque_pthread_cond_t*, _opaque_pthread_mutex_t*) + 4 (__threading_support:335)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&) + 20 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
4   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_1>(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&, fml::Concurrent... + 52 (__mutex_base:398)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 64 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:80)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0::operator()() const + 268 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:26)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(... + 268 (invoke.h:403)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 268 (thread:284)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 344 (thread:295)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__libcpp_condvar_wait[abi:v15000](_opaque_pthread_cond_t*, _opaque_pthread_mutex_t*) + 4 (__threading_support:335)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&) + 20 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
4   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_1>(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&, fml::Concurrent... + 52 (__mutex_base:398)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 64 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:80)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0::operator()() const + 268 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:26)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(... + 268 (invoke.h:403)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 268 (thread:284)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 344 (thread:295)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__libcpp_condvar_wait[abi:v15000](_opaque_pthread_cond_t*, _opaque_pthread_mutex_t*) + 4 (__threading_support:335)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&) + 20 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
4   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_1>(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&, fml::Concurrent... + 52 (__mutex_base:398)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 64 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:80)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0::operator()() const + 268 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:26)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(... + 268 (invoke.h:403)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 268 (thread:284)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 344 (thread:295)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__libcpp_condvar_wait[abi:v15000](_opaque_pthread_cond_t*, _opaque_pthread_mutex_t*) + 4 (__threading_support:335)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&) + 20 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
4   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_1>(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&, fml::Concurrent... + 52 (__mutex_base:398)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 64 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:80)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0::operator()() const + 268 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:26)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(... + 268 (invoke.h:403)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 268 (thread:284)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 344 (thread:295)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__libcpp_condvar_wait[abi:v15000](_opaque_pthread_cond_t*, _opaque_pthread_mutex_t*) + 4 (__threading_support:335)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&) + 20 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
4   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_1>(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&, fml::Concurrent... + 52 (__mutex_base:398)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 64 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:80)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0::operator()() const + 268 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:26)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(... + 268 (invoke.h:403)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 268 (thread:284)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 344 (thread:295)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__libcpp_condvar_wait[abi:v15000](_opaque_pthread_cond_t*, _opaque_pthread_mutex_t*) + 4 (__threading_support:335)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000104bb053c std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&) + 20 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
4   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_1>(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&, fml::Concurrent... + 52 (__mutex_base:398)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 64 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:80)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0::operator()() const + 268 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:26)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(... + 268 (invoke.h:403)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_execute[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LI... + 268 (thread:284)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000104e3c13c void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_N... + 344 (thread:295)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef8150 kevent + 8 (:-1)
1   Flutter                         0x000000010502be18 dart::bin::EventHandlerImplementation::EventHandlerEntry(unsigned long) + 428 (eventhandler_macos.cc:455)
2   Flutter                         0x000000010505c0d0 dart::bin::ThreadStart(void*) + 44 (thread_macos.cc:87)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8


Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000000000062dc   x5: 0x000000010922f090   x6: 0x0000000000000014   x7: 0x000000000000003e
    x8: 0x1d1423d2b60b51de   x9: 0x1d1423d3db5be1de  x10: 0x00000000000007fd  x11: 0x0000000000000018
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x00000000f662d050  x14: 0x00000000f682d800  x15: 0x000000000002d800
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016d50b000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000000000a803  x21: 0x000000016d50b0e0  x22: 0x00000001053fb7d8  x23: 0x0000000108835e00
   x24: 0x0000000281074d88  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x000000016d508f28  x27: 0x07ffffffffffffff
   x28: 0x7fffffffffffffe0   fp: 0x000000016d508d00   lr: 0x00000001f197da9c
    sp: 0x000000016d508ce0   pc: 0x00000001d3ef6334 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

edit: adding screenshot of the place when pressing 'Open in Project' on Crash in Xcode:

[image: Xcode error opens this]

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ed14fc mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ed0884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c0ae58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a5c04308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a64e2b38 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 568 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1374)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a706530c __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   grpc                            0x0000000103f49630 gpr_cv_wait + 124 (sync_posix.cc:126)
3   grpc                            0x0000000103e626e0 grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*) + 180 (executor.cc:238)
4   grpc                            0x0000000103f54270 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::operator()(void*) const + 116 (thd_posix.cc:140)
5   grpc                            0x0000000103f54270 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140 (thd_posix.cc:110)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   grpc                            0x0000000103f49630 gpr_cv_wait + 124 (sync_posix.cc:126)
3   grpc                            0x0000000103e626e0 grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*) + 180 (executor.cc:238)
4   grpc                            0x0000000103f54270 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::operator()(void*) const + 116 (thd_posix.cc:140)
5   grpc                            0x0000000103f54270 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140 (thd_posix.cc:110)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   grpc                            0x0000000103f49620 gpr_cv_wait + 108 (sync_posix.cc:140)
3   grpc                            0x0000000103f58158 wait_until(long long) + 72 (timer_manager.cc:200)
4   grpc                            0x0000000103f58158 timer_main_loop() + 460 (timer_manager.cc:255)
5   grpc                            0x0000000103f58158 timer_thread(void*) + 552 (timer_manager.cc:284)
6   grpc                            0x0000000103f54270 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::operator()(void*) const + 116 (thd_posix.cc:140)
7   grpc                            0x0000000103f54270 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140 (thd_posix.cc:110)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   grpc                            0x0000000103f49630 gpr_cv_wait + 124 (sync_posix.cc:126)
3   grpc                            0x0000000103f58158 wait_until(long long) + 72 (timer_manager.cc:200)
4   grpc                            0x0000000103f58158 timer_main_loop() + 460 (timer_manager.cc:255)
5   grpc                            0x0000000103f58158 timer_thread(void*) + 552 (timer_manager.cc:284)
6   grpc                            0x0000000103f54270 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::operator()(void*) const + 116 (thd_posix.cc:140)
7   grpc                            0x0000000103f54270 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140 (thd_posix.cc:110)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001ba816efc std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28 (__threading_support:428)
3   leveldb                         0x00000001047c4bb4 leveldb::port::CondVar::Wait() + 24 (port_stdcxx.h:77)
4   leveldb                         0x00000001047c4bb4 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::BackgroundThreadMain() + 40 (env_posix.cc:785)
5   leveldb                         0x00000001047c4bb4 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::BackgroundThreadEntryPoint(leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv*) + 80 (env_posix.cc:700)
6   leveldb                         0x00000001047c4c50 decltype(std::declval<void (*)(leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv*)>()(std::declval<leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv*>())) std::__1::__invoke[abi:v15006]<void (*)(leveldb::(anonymous ... + 8 (invoke.h:394)
7   leveldb                         0x00000001047c4c50 void std::__1::__thread_execute[abi:v15006]<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv*... + 8 (thread:290)
8   leveldb                         0x00000001047c4c50 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v15006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(leveldb::(anonymous namesp... + 52 (thread:301)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 24 name:
Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980460 _pthread_cond_wait + 1292 (pthread_cond.c:640)
2   Flutter                         0x00000001051a38dc dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128 (os_thread_macos.cc:430)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::MonitorLocker::WaitMicros(long long) + 8 (lockers.h:181)
4   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 536 (thread_pool.cc:183)
5   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 668 (thread_pool.cc:330)
6   Flutter                         0x00000001051a32a8 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 288 (os_thread_macos.cc:132)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 25 name:
Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980460 _pthread_cond_wait + 1292 (pthread_cond.c:640)
2   Flutter                         0x00000001051a38dc dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128 (os_thread_macos.cc:430)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::MonitorLocker::WaitMicros(long long) + 8 (lockers.h:181)
4   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 536 (thread_pool.cc:183)
5   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 668 (thread_pool.cc:330)
6   Flutter                         0x00000001051a32a8 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 288 (os_thread_macos.cc:132)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 26 name:
Thread 26:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980460 _pthread_cond_wait + 1292 (pthread_cond.c:640)
2   Flutter                         0x00000001051a38dc dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128 (os_thread_macos.cc:430)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::MonitorLocker::WaitMicros(long long) + 8 (lockers.h:181)
4   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 536 (thread_pool.cc:183)
5   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 668 (thread_pool.cc:330)
6   Flutter                         0x00000001051a32a8 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 288 (os_thread_macos.cc:132)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 27 name:
Thread 27:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d3ef60cc __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1980460 _pthread_cond_wait + 1292 (pthread_cond.c:640)
2   Flutter                         0x00000001051a38dc dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128 (os_thread_macos.cc:430)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::MonitorLocker::WaitMicros(long long) + 8 (lockers.h:181)
4   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 536 (thread_pool.cc:183)
5   Flutter                         0x00000001051e1420 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 668 (thread_pool.cc:330)
6   Flutter                         0x00000001051a32a8 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 288 (os_thread_macos.cc:132)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f197cbfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985758 thread_start + 8

Thread 28:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 29:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1985744 start_wqthread + 0
```

Comment: you should get build execution failed message in xcode. can you share that

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand you well, I am very new to XCode/iOS. The build doesn't fail. I can build the app successfully. The app crashes on some devices randomly